# How to loop through excel twice using Apache Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Using Apache Jmeter, I want to loop through all rows in an excel **twice**.
This can't be done using a normal [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) as you can Recycle or stop on EOF, but not defin the number of iterations trough the file.

### This is what I tried:

1. > login
2. > Search for document, using data from a [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
3. > logout

Comment: Just a thought: Use a batch file to copy the input file and start jmeter.bat. In your script use the two files and 2 CSV data sets to loop trough the same file twice (the original and the copied  one).

Comment: @Cagy79 I want to loop through step2 and step 3 only depend on data in excel

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this, kindly use suggested design as a reference:

- [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) (1 thread, 2 loops)

  - [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) with the following code:

    ```
    org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().closeFile("file.csv");
    vars.put("varFromCsv", "");
    ```
  - [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller), condition: `${__javaScript("${varFromCsv}" != "<EOF>",)}`

    - CSV Data Set Config (Filename: `file.csv`, Variable Names: `varFromCsv`, everything set to `False`, Sharing Mode: `All threads`
    - [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller), condition `"${varFromCsv}" != "<EOF>"`

      - Your test logic goes here

Demo:

[image: JMeter CSV Loop Twice]

Example Test Plan just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="3.1" jmeter="3.1 r1770033">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">2</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1487666779000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1487666779000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <BeanShellSampler guiclass="BeanShellSamplerGui" testclass="BeanShellSampler" testname="Beanshell Sampler" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.query">org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().closeFile(&quot;file.csv&quot;);
vars.put(&quot;varFromCsv&quot;, &quot;&quot;);</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.parameters"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="BeanShellSampler.resetInterpreter">false</boolProp>
        </BeanShellSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <WhileController guiclass="WhileControllerGui" testclass="WhileController" testname="While Controller" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="WhileController.condition">${__javaScript(&quot;${varFromCsv}&quot; != &quot;&lt;EOF&gt;&quot;,)}</stringProp>
        </WhileController>
        <hashTree>
          <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="CSV Data Set Config" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="filename">file.csv</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="recycle">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.all</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="variableNames">varFromCsv</stringProp>
          </CSVDataSet>
          <hashTree/>
          <IfController guiclass="IfControllerPanel" testclass="IfController" testname="If Controller" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="IfController.condition">&quot;${varFromCsv}&quot; != &quot;&lt;EOF&gt;&quot;</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="IfController.evaluateAll">false</boolProp>
          </IfController>
          <hashTree>
            <BeanShellSampler guiclass="BeanShellSamplerGui" testclass="BeanShellSampler" testname="${varFromCsv}" enabled="true">
              <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.query">Thread.sleep(100);</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.filename"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="BeanShellSampler.parameters"></stringProp>
              <boolProp name="BeanShellSampler.resetInterpreter">false</boolProp>
            </BeanShellSampler>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Reference material: [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter)

Comment: i have 10 request , i want to loop from 6th request to 10 th request ,depend on data in excel.